# clickonce application does not work in Windows 10

Tags: .net, winforms, deployment, windows-10, clickonce

I am trying to run a windows application through Task Scheduler on Windows 10. A window appears and disappears in no time but application does not execute. 
In windows 8 and Windows 7 its working fine but the issue only is with windows 10. I have checked even logs but there is nothing i can find about my application. Can anyone please help out? I have been looking for the solutions since many days.